# Standards or examples of graphically combining hover and sorting, in a column header?

Tags: hover, sorting, column-headers

I want to combine two things in the list header in our product:

1. **Sort highlight** like Spotify. We have a small sorting arrow indicator, but adding a highlight to the header of the sorted column makes the sorting much clearer. You can click three times; two directions of sorting, and the third click removes the sorting, and thereby the highlight too.
2. **Hover effect** like windows explorer. We have a filter button that only shows when hovering the column. Without the hover effect on the column header, the button popping up in the right end would feel malplacé.

My question: How do I combine these two effects, graphically? Is there a **standard** or any **examples** of combining these two graphical effects? I have been experimenting with borders and gradients of different strength, but it ends up a mess.

The problem is that both these graphical effects changes the background image. I have to find a combination that can show both the hover and press effects "on top of" the sorted effect. I find it hard to find a way of designing background images that clearly shows what state the sorting is in, no matter where the user keeps her mouse.

In the image you see that the examples I found does not combine these effects.

[image]

Comment: You say you've experimented with borders and gradients - how so? My initial response would be that you go with Border Only for a hover effect, and then Highlight for the sorting effect. Therefore when you hover over a field, regardless of whether it has an active highlight then the border of that cell appears.

Comment: @JonW: I experimented with the borders together with different gradients, but never border only. I like the thought of the gradient making it look convex, and then concave when pressed. The stronger gradient makes it hard to differ different gradients in different highlights though, so a border only might just do the trick.

Comment: @JonW: That calls for two different borders though; one for hover, and one for press.

Comment: That depends on the colourscheme you go with though. I still think you could just have two properties - border and background, both unrelated to eachother. If you hover you get the border=true and if you select it then you get background=true, with combinations of both depending on what is hovered over and what has been selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this need, following the track I started in the question, using 4 different images.

1. Original gradient
2. Increased gradient
3. Flipped gradient
4. Inreased and flipped gradient.

[image: column headers hovered and sorted]

Note that the state order of normal mouse movements typically is:

- 1-2-3-5-4, for sorting an unsorted list, or
- 4-5-6-5-4, for resorting in the opposite order, or
- 4-5-6-2-1, for unsorting again.

(Same as Spotify)

Answer (score 2):

You could do the sorted column highlight not in the the header but in the column itself.
You could also use a flat color for sorted, and another shade of that color for hover.

Comment: +1. A great visual effect by itself, but it conflicts with other color coding in the cells. The question is about column headers.